# csv.writer returning long strings in each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I've been having some more problems. After you've modified my code well into this.

```
import csv

mesta=["Ljubljana","Kranj","Skofja Loka","Trzin"]
opis=["ti","mene","ti mene","ne ti mene"]
delodajalci=["GENI","MOJEDELO","MOJADELNICA","HSE"]
ime=["domen","maja","andraz","sanja"]
datum=["2.1.2014","5.10.2014","11.12.2014","5.5.2014"]

with open('sth.csv','w') as csvfile:
    zapis = csv.writer(csvfile)
    zapis.writerows(zip(ime,delodajalci,opis,datum,mesta))
```

I have one aditional question. How do I get each piece of my output to have it's own cell and not have 5 really long rows divided by `,` signs. Since now my output looks like:

```
domen,GENI,ti,2.1.2014,Ljubljana
maja,MOJEDELO,mene,5.10.2014,Kranj
andraz,MOJADELNICA,ti mene,11.12.2014,Skofja Loka
sanja,HSE,ne ti mene,5.5.2014,Trzin
```

I hope you will be able to help me. Thank you in advance. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

So a csv file (Comma-separated values file) is meant to have commas on really long rows as you indicated. To open the file with each value in a cell, say for excel, if you change the extension of the file to .csv it will likely be taken care of. Otherwise, you may need to import the file and indicate that the separators are commas. If you don't have excel, you can try googling for csv viewer (there are many free versions available). In either case, your output looks correct, I think you just need a bit of help opening the file in your program of choice.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `csv` module can also use delimiters other than commas, if you tell it to. [Read it's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters), especially regarding the formatting parameters. The questioner may want something like `zapis = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter="\t")`.

Comment: Thank you for that, but actually another problem occurs then. Let's say I have one cell in csv that looks like this:

Delovni terapevt I (intenzivna nega, rehab. enota) m/\xc5\xbe,Univerzitetni rehabilitacijski in\xc5\xa1titut RS - So\xc4\x8da,13.02.2015,Ljubljana

as you can see that my input was stored like so:
a=Delovni terapevt I (intenzivna nega, rehab. enota) m/\xc5\xbe
b=Univerzitetni rehabilitacijski in\xc5\xa1titut RS - So\xc4\x8da
c=13.02.2015
d=Ljubljana
And now as my example code shows it should all be in it's own cell while opened with excel I agree.

Comment: But if I open it in Excel it understands commas everywhere to be the separator, so it divides my data at Delovni terapevt | (intenzivna nega
and then goes on to rehab. enota ... 
Do you know of any methods to make this problem go away, maybe?

Comment: @Swish41: Check out the documentation I linked. There are a variety of ways you can have the CSV data quoted, though you may need to tell Excel to use the same quote style when it imports the data.

Comment: @Swish41 The format for SO is one question per post; if you have another question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). And if this answer helped solve your query, don't forget to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @Swish41: Try adding a `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` argument to the `csv.writer(csvfile)` call which will make it quote fields which contain the `,` delimiter character.